# Constructor not defined: [Asia1Activation].<Constructor>() at line 27 column 31

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class Asia1Activation {

    public Asia1__c thisAsia1 {get; set;}
    public Boolean isSuccess {get; set;}
    public Boolean isActivated {get; set;}
    public Boolean onLoad {get; set;}
    public Boolean isEnabled {get; set;}
    public Boolean isExpired {get; set;}
    public Boolean isMessageShown {get; set;}
    public String messageResult {get; set;}
    Boolean proceedWithUpdate;

    public Asia1Activation (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.thisAsia1 = (Asia1__c)controller.getRecord();

        checkIfExptired();
        isActivated = FALSE;
        isSuccess = FALSE;
        isEnabled = FALSE; 
        isMessageShown = FALSE;
        onLoad = True;

    }


    /*
     *@Description: calls Asia1 Webservice to verify Asia1 Credentials
     *@Parameters: Map<String, Object> 
     *@Return: Boolean Status of the Response of Callout
    */
    public void checkIfExptired() {

        if (thisAsia1.Base_Date_Expiration__c < date.today()) {

                thisAsia1.Is_Link_Expired_Used__c = true;
                proceedWithUpdate = true;
        }
....
```

The test class looks like:

```
@isTest (Seealldata = TRUE)
public class Asia1Activation_Test {

    static testmethod void unitTest1(){


        Asia1__c a1 = new Asia1__c();
        a1.User_ID_LDAP_ID__c = 'userId27';
        a1.Status__c = 'Pending Creation';
        a1.Id_Already_Active__c = false;
        a1.Enabled__c = false;
        a1.Password__c = '13456722';
        a1.Display_Name__c = 'userId27';
        a1.email__c = 'userId27@sample.com';
        insert a1;
        Test.startTest();

        Asia1Activation aoa = new Asia1Activation();
        aoa.thisAsia1 = a1;
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new BatchServiceFacadeMockTest());
        aoa.verifyAccount();
        Test.stopTest();
    }//end of unitTest1
    static testmethod void unitTest2(){
        Asia1__c a1 = new Asia1__c();
        a1.User_ID_LDAP_ID__c = 'userId27';
        a1.Status__c = 'Pending Creation';
        a1.Id_Already_Active__c = false;
        a1.Enabled__c = false;
        a1.Password__c = '13456722';
        a1.Display_Name__c = 'userId27';
        a1.email__c = 'userId27@sample.com';
        insert a1;
        Test.startTest();

        Asia1Activation aoa = new Asia1Activation();
        aoa.thisAsia1 = a1;
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new BatchServiceFacadeMockFailTest());
        aoa.verifyAccount();
        Test.stopTest();
    }//end of unitTest1

}
```

I get an error:

> Constructor not defined: [Asia1Activation].() at line 27
>   column 31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is right - you have not defined an empty constructor. In your definition above, you are passing in a `standardController` (as you should do)

You need to create a `standardController` and pass in your custom object in it's constructor.

You then need to make your controller extension and pass in the standard controller.

Do something like this:

```
Asia1__c asia1 = new Asia1__c();
ApexPages.StandardController stdController = new ApexPages.StandardController(asia1);
Asia1Activation aoa;
aoa = new Asia1Activation (stdController);
```